# HTTP Post issue

Tags: java, http, post

My code is shown below and prints out all of the input from the client.

Except, when I try and read it, no post data comes through...

```
while ((s = input.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

My Post data:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 27
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: (http://) localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.97 Safari/537.22
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: (http://) localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

So I don't recieve any data, except I put a form in my HTML

```
<form method="post">
    TestText: <input type="text" name="test1"><br>
    TestText2: <input type="text" name="test2">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So any ideas?

I've coded my own HTTP server, so I've implemented a method to get POST, GET and other stuff

Comment: Are you using Apache HttpClient or Servlet or another technology?

Comment: I can see that your form doesn't have an action, probably causing the problems.

Comment: It'll post to itself if it doesn't have an action attribute. I don't know if that is what he is trying to do.

Comment: `action` is required on a `form` tag, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

Comment: Not in HTML5, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: Also action is for HTML, he is sending his request from Java.

Comment: Request is from Java? `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome`

Comment: No, the request is from chrome. It's the problem that no POST data shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cannot yet post comments (thanks SO), I am going to post my comment as an answer.

Since the `Content-Length` header is not 0, I assume that the request body does include the form data even though you did not include it in your post data.

If that is the case, then we need to see where the `input` variable comes from in order to know why it does not include the expected data. I would suggest that you modify your questions and add the code which sets the `input` variable.

Comment: This is the issue, Content-Length shows a number, but I don't recieve the POST data. input is an 'InputStream' class, which is the socket's input stream.

Comment: In that case, I am not quite sure how you are able to call readLine() on the `input` variable, as the `InputStream` interface has no readLine() method.

Instead, I would try:

`StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
int s;
while ((s = input.read()) > -1)
    str.append(s);
System.out.println(str.toString());`